# Chrome extension add listener to content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to add an even listener to a content script?

I'd like to send a message, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage("hello")` and listen for it in another content script. However, only the listener in `background.js` gets notified and not the listener in `second_script.js`.

Is it possible to listen for messages in content scripts? If so, how?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  console.log(request)
  return true
});
```

Comment: The listener is correctly added but you need chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tabId as the first parameter here. See an example in the [messaging](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) documentation.

Comment: BTW you don't need `return true` there. It's only needed if you call sendResponse from an asynchronous nested callback. Using it unnecessarily may cause error messages being displayed in the console.